# How to Optimize queries inside for loop in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, optimization, django-views

I have a legacy code of application on which I am working. I installed Django debug toolbar and noticed nearly 1600 queries being executed on a single page of the application on a single request. After observing the trace of Django debug toolbar I noticed that the view function has nested queries inside for loop which calls model method. And further model method has another for loop inside first for loop calling another model method. Now after reading about django query optimization on the internet I learnt that this is very bad practice. But after spending 2 days on it I am not able to figure out how to optimize it. I am not able to figure out any alternate method with which I can replace that for loop with a query which brings all the data in one query.

Below I am posting the Models, respective model methods and views which are being called.

**views.py**

```
def course_modules(request, course_id, msg=None):
    user = request.user
    course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
    
    learning_modules = course.get_learning_modules()
    context = {"course": course, "user": user, "msg": msg}
    course_status = CourseStatus.objects.filter(
            course=course, user=user
        )
    context['course_percentage'] = course_status.first().percent_completed

    context['modules'] = [
        (module, module.get_module_complete_percent(course, user))
        for module in learning_modules
        ]

    if course_status:
        course_status = course_status.first()
        if not course_status.grade:
            course_status.set_grade()
        context['grade'] = course_status.get_grade()
    return my_render_to_response(request, 'course_modules.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class LearningModule(models.Model):
    """ Learning Module to maintain learning units"""
    learning_unit = models.ManyToManyField(LearningUnit,
                                           related_name="learning_unit")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="module_creator",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_prerequisite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    check_prerequisite_passes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    html_data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_trial = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_module_complete_percent(self, course, user):
        units = self.get_learning_units()
        if not units:
            percent = 0.0
        else:
            status_list = [unit.get_completion_status(user, course)
                           for unit in units]
            count = status_list.count("completed")
            percent = round((count / units.count()) * 100)
        return percent

    def get_learning_units(self):
        return self.learning_unit.order_by("order")

class LearningUnit(models.Model):
    """ Maintain order of lesson and quiz added in the course """
    order = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, null=True, blank=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, null=True, blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_prerequisite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_completion_status(self, user, course):
        course_status = CourseStatus.objects.filter(
            user_id=user.id, course_id=course.id
        )
        state = "not attempted"
        if course_status.exists():
            if course_status.first().completed_units.filter(id=self.id):
                state = "completed"
            elif self.type == "quiz":
                state = self.quiz.get_answerpaper_status(user, course)
            elif course_status.first().current_unit == self:
                state = "inprogress"
        return state


class Course(models.Model):
    """ Course for students"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    enrollment = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=enrollment_methods)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='students')
    requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='requests')
    rejected = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='rejected')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teachers')
    is_trial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    instructions = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    view_grade = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    learning_module = models.ManyToManyField(LearningModule,
                                             related_name='learning_module')

    def get_learning_modules(self):
        return self.learning_module.select_related(
                'creator'
            ).prefetch_related(
                'learning_unit'
            ).filter(is_trial=False).order_by("order")
```

I would really love to have a feedback on this, or a if someone could point me into right direction with which I can tackle this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the `LearningModule.get_learning_units` method and the `Course` model to your question? It's the `get_module_complete_percent` call in the list comprehension that's causing the issue right?

Comment: @IainShelvington Updated the question. Yes list comprehension is the problem. It is doing too many things at once, and I am not able to simplify it.